# :require data.json in Clojure doesn't seem to be working

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I am new to Clojure and have been stuck for a while on the :require. I am using lein and included in my project.clj

```
 :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
             [http-kit "2.1.18"]
             [org.clojure/data.json "0.2.6"]])
```

I checked the class path and tried to :require the data.json as it said on the data.json Github page but it says cannot find on classpath. I tried

```
:require [org.httpkit.client :as http]
         [clojure.string :as str]
         [clojure.data.json :as json]))
```

along with org.clojure.data.json and a whole bunch of other things. In my classpath it says

```
.m2/repository/org/clojure/data.json/0.2.6/data.json-0.2.6.jar
```

So I know it is in my classpath.

Thanks

*Edit*

My full ns script in my core.clj is

```
(ns myproject.core
  (import [java.net URLEncoder])
  (:require [org.httpkit.client :as http]
             [clojure.string :as str]
             [clojure.data.json :as json]))
```

Just for clarification I am importing one project into another using the /checkouts/. When I delete the data.json line it works but doesn't work with it.

Comment: Where do you put your `require` snippet? project.clj or your namespace file?

Comment: @Piotrek I put it in the core.clj file. I tried other projects and can't seem to get them working.

Comment: You listed `org.clojure/data.json` in your deps, but requiring `cheshire.core` in your file.

Comment: I accidentally copied the wrong thing. It is fixed now.

Comment: What's your error message?

Comment: @Piotrek 1. Unhandled java.io.FileNotFoundException
   Could not locate clojure/data/json__init.class or
   clojure/data/json.clj on classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're using lein try running `lein install` - this should make the jars available to you.

I'm using the same library in a current project and my `project.clj` and `ns :require` are both identical to yours.

Comment: I must have tried that quite a few times but finally something changed and it worked. Thanks.